# how to dynamically add script tags at the end of the body element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to remove render blocking javascript. So, i am trying to dynamically add `script` tags at the end of the `body` element after page has loaded.

I have 7 `script` tags that i want to add dynamically. One of the `script` tag loads `jQuery` using a CDN. Remaining 6 `script` tags load javascript that depends on `jQuery`.

I have put all the links to javascript files in an array and then using a loop, i am creating a `script` element, adding required attributes on it and appending it to the `body` element.

**Problem:**

Problem is that when i view the page in the browser, i get errors in the console regarding `jQuery` not being defined.

I am adding the `script` tags in the correct order and i have verified that `script` tags are indeed added at the end of the `body` element and are added in the correct order.

This problem occurs everytime on initial load and if i refresh the page then sometimes scripts are loaded correctly and sometimes i get the same error that `jQuery` is undefined.

As a result of this problem, some of the animations on the webpage are not triggered and also i am using `slick` carousel. When javascript is not loaded correctly, all the images, that should be displayed in `slick` carousel, are displayed one after the other.

**Question:**

Why is `jQuery` undefined when other scripts, that are dependant on `jQuery`, execute? What is the correct way to dynamically add `script` tags in the `html`?

**Code:**

This is how i am adding `script` tags in the `html`. All scripts are loaded from local filesystem except `jQuery` and `slick carousel` which are loaded via a CDN.

```
<script>
  function loadJs() {
    const arr = [
      "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js",
      "//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js",
      "./js/jquery.waypoints.min.js",
      "./js/jquery.counterup.min.js",
      "./js/wow.min.js",
      "./js/lazysizes.min.js",
      "./js/loso.js",
    ];

    for (let srcLink of arr) {
        let script = document.createElement("script");

        script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
        script.setAttribute("src", srcLink);

        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }
  }

  window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    loadJs();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: jquery is not defined error may occurs if some of our html elements has jquery functions which has been getting excuted or external files excuting before your jquery library is getting loaded. If you put the code in a codepen will be good for understanding.

Comment: @Jerrinstephen i have created a [Repl](https://repl.it/repls/BreakableSomberProcedurallanguage#js/loso.js). You could download repl as a zip and open it in chrome. I have also tested this in safari browser and i see the same problem but somehow the problem is not reproduced in the repl

Comment: @Jerrinstephen were you able to find the cause of the problem? i am still stuck at this problem

Answer (score 0):

@Nick I have found some issues hope it will be helpful for you.

1. In array of loading js and css files you missed https:// for slick carousel  js and css files
2. when you tried to load the js with a timer like this

   ```
   for (let srcLink of arr) {
     setTimeout(() => {
       let script = document.createElement("script");
       script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
       script.setAttribute("src", srcLink);
       document.body.appendChild(script);
     }, 100);
   }
   ```

Files will be loaded one after the another so we wont get error. The error occurs depending on your internet connection speed, so by this way of loading the files we can avoid the error[image]

As you can see in the image didnt found any issue while loading files , have refreshed several times and checked.

3. If you tried to load the file without the timer , will be causing the issue based upon your internet connectivity speed.
   [image]

As you can we are getting error in console.[image]

Try

- Load files with normal script tag
- Load files with an timer.

Comment: if i add all the files one after the other, without the timer, are they not executing in the order they are inserted in the html?

Comment: script tag are blocking elements, second script tag cant be loaded until the first script tag is parsed or executed. since in your case you are loading the script tag in array method, script tag started to load before the another script tag is loaded. You can avoid it by using timer or load it using a script tag in order.

Comment: _since in your case you are loading the script tag in array method_ can you elaborate on this statement? As far as i understand, i am just creating `script` elements and adding them at the end of the body. They start loading once they are added at the end of the body. So why the newly added script loading before previous script has loaded completely?

Comment: a normal array for each will loop through the array and will do the operation which has been given. The same way array for each will loop through the script tag array and add to the body of an element as given without knowing whether the previous script tag(an element in array) is loaded or not. This causes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Call this function with an array of script URLs and it's guaranteed to load and execute them in order by calling itself only once the current script is loaded.

```
 /**
 * This has to serialize the JS loading because sometimes one depends on another.  Also can't
 * give back control to the View until they're all loaded
 *
 * @param {array} scripts paths
 * @returns
 */
async addScripts(scripts) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        /* create a script element and append it as the last child in body */
        const $script = document.createElement('script')
        document.body.appendChild($script).src = scripts[0]
        $script.onload = (e) => scripts.length > 1 ? addScripts(scripts.slice(1)).then(resolve) : resolve()
    })
}
```